# I have just seen some already answered questions under “Unanswered” category

Tags: support, unanswered-questions

I just went to page : **https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress?sort=unanswered&pageSize=30**

Getting many questions which have already given answers.

Ex : **[How do I use SCM with a PHP app such as Wordpress?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118235/how-do-i-use-scm-with-a-php-app-such-as-wordpress) - This question have many answers given but still it is coming under "Unanswered" category.**

And found many questions which have lot of answers. So is this bug or I am in misunderstanding?

I think those questions should be removed from "Unasnwered" category which have at least one answer.

Comment: First:  there's a lot of caching, and it may take a moment for it to catch up.  Second:  I'm not seeing any answered questions in that section.

Comment: @Makoto - Thanks for reply , But I am getting many like : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/wordpress?page=937&sort=unanswered&pagesize=30  - Most of question has answers in this page..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I see what the confusion is - none of those questions have an *upvoted* answer.

Hover over the "Unanswered" tab, and it'll tell you - it's only going to show questions with no upvoted answers.

At first I thought you were seeing something unusual in general, but I double-checked this behavior in another tag, and that seems to be the case.

Comment: You are right, thanks to help me to get rid from misunderstanding.